# In what book are there advertisements in dreams?

Tags: story-identification

I read a part of a book about a man in a dystopia. Everyone was constantly entertained, but books were forbidden (I think). The mother of the main character was constantly listening to the radio. That's all I can remember.

Comment: This reminds me of the Futurama episode, "A Fishful of Dollars" but I can't find what story the 'ads within dreams' thing was lifted from.

Comment: It was Montag's wife that had a 'seashell' radio practically glued in her ear.

Comment: There is a problem here, since there were no advertisements in dreams in _Fahrenheit 451_.  I've read the novel a number of times and just re-read it a few months ago.  I recently re-watched the movie, as well, and there are no advertisements in dreams in there, either.  While the rest fits, this was not an element of the book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm drawing a blank of the mother, but the rest sounds like Bradbury's classic [Fahrenheit 451](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451)

Comment: Yes, Fahrenheit 451 is the one! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem :). Though I have to admit I don't remember the bit with ads in dreams, but it's been a while since I've read it.

Comment: Yes, I think I might have mixed up the episode of Futurama with Fahrenheit 451. Very strange :P